# coffee script - remove from one array based on second array contents

Tags: coffeescript

I have 2 arrays - one has attribute called vcdName and the other has attribute called name.  I want to remove from array 1 all entries where I find the value of vcdName in the second array.  So:
array one
data...vcdName=a
data...vcdName=b

array two
data...name=a

I want to filter array one and remove the first entry (because vcdName value a is found in array two).

I understand I can use lodash functions and I tried the following.  I believeusing is will return me those entries that match and I need to put in filteredArray those entries where no match is found in arraytwo.

```
filteredArray = _.filter(@arrayone, (vcd) -> vcd.vcdName is @arraytwo)
```

I hope I have not gotten too confusing.  It feels this should be moderately easier than I am making it.

Generically I need to do this

```
for each entry in arrayone
  for each entry in arraytwo
    does entry from arrayone.vcdName == arraytwo.name - if yes then I do not want that entry from arrayone
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is in js core so I don't see why you'd need to use the lodash function, but anyway you can do it like this:

```
arraytwo_names = @arraytwo.reduce (dict, entry) ->
  dict[entry.name] = true
  dict
, {}

results = @arrayone.filter (x) ->
  !arraytwo_names[x.vcdName]
```

The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is not strictly speaking necessary, since you could loop through arraytwo each iteration of the filter, but it is an optimization and makes the runtime O(N) and not O(N^2).

Comment: I am new to coffee so a coworker suggested using lodash.  I went with your suggestion and it worked as I needed.  My only issue is I do not understandwhat what the first part of the answer does.  If you might be able to expand to explain that would be appreciated.  But suffice to say I truly appreciate your taking the time to provide this solution and I have used it with success.